# How to get CT-Scan Images to other machine in the network

Tags: c#

I am working on project of a Diagnostic Centre, where the user  manage their patient data. Everything has completed.

But, the customer want to load the CT-Scan Images to the software. But we don't have any idea of ct-scan machine or its software. We can handle only jpg, png, gif type of images in our c#.net win-application and can store in SQL Server. But we don't have any idea to handle that problem.

Please suggest me how to get ct-scan images to any other machine in the network from CT-scan computer. Any software or company or anything that can help. Please help.

Comment: Talk to the CT scan company - I bet they have a viewer available....

Answer (score 0):

A lot of CT scans are in a custom format from the company DICOM.  I don't know whether that is what  you're dealing with or not.

http://www.cabiatl.com/mricro/dicom/